# Android: BitmapDrawable.Draw(Canvas) Doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, bitmap, draw

I am trying to tile a 20x20 background onto my Custom View but for some reason I am unable too.

```
    BitmapDrawable background;
    background = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.back));
    background.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    background.draw(canvas);
```

Does anyone have an idea why it isn't working?

Answer (score 13):

You can use BitmapDrawable, but you have to set the bounds first so it knows how much tiling to do:

```
BitmapDrawable background;
background = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.back));

//in this case, you want to tile the entire view
background.setBounds(0, 0, myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight());

background.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
background.draw(canvas);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting warnings in your log regarding SKImageDecoder failing. If you are creating the resource via xml you need to retreive it via `(BitmapDrawable) getResources().getdrawable(id)`

Answer (score -1):

You have it backwards.  Instead of passing your View's canvas to the bitmap's draw method, draw your Bitmap to the View's canvas using Canvas.drawBitmap

Comment: But drawBitmap can't use a BitmapDrawable only a Bitmap, while only the BitmapDrawable is able to be tiled?

Comment: I don't know of a one-liner to draw it out tiled as you would with BitmapDrawable, but if you decode a Bitmap instead of a BitmapDrawable and make a very simple loop calling drawBitmap inside the loop it would work just the same.  Perhaps use the overload that takes the source and destination rectangles and update the destination rectangle in the loop, or use the overload that takes two floats (top and left) and update them in the loop.